# How do I teach ogr2ogr about a projection?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-server, ogr2ogr

I have [JSON generated from ArcGIS](https://github.com/codefortulsa/OpenTulsaDataTools/blob/366fc3d899ffe4f74a7a7e29bd3963db01cb4253/mirror/Neighborhood%20Reinvestment%20Areas/Current%20Tulsa%20Neighborhood%20Reinvestment%20Areas.arcgis.json) that I want to convert to GeoJSON in EPSG 4326.  This fails:

```
$ ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON -t_srs EPSG:4326 out.geo.json in.arcgis.json OGRGeoJSON
ERROR 6: EPSG PCS/GCS code 102100 not found in EPSG support files.  Is this a valid
EPSG coordinate system?
```

I found [a forum post](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=984&t=288607) that says 102100 can be changed to 3857, which is mathematically identical.  So, this works, with the same error message:

```
$ ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON -s_srs EPSG:3857 -t_srs EPSG:4326 out.geo.json in.arcgis.json OGRGeoJSON 
ERROR 6: EPSG PCS/GCS code 102100 not found in EPSG support files.  Is this a valid
EPSG coordinate system?
```

However, I have several files in the 102100 projection system.  I'd like to teach ogr2ogr about the 102100 projection, so I can script the conversion.  Is there a way to update the config so that 102100 is recognized and treated the same as 3857?

*Update* - This data is from the REST API of ArgGIS Server 9.3.1.  If I don't specify an output spatial reference, then I get 102100, which they define as the projected coordinate system ["WGS_1984_Web_Mercator_Auxiliary_Sphere"](http://maps.cityoftulsa.org/arcgis/SDK/REST/pcs.html).  A much easier way to accomplish my goal is to ask for the desired projection, with the `outSR=4326` query parameter.  The question is still valid if you don't have access to original data.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As 102100 and 3857 are mathematically identical, I think you can safely ignore the errors and just continue with overriding the source srs using the **-s_srs** flag.

You can try adding the definition for 102100 in your $GDAL_DATA$ but it's not really recommended. If you really want to do it though, here's the method and the accompanying warning from [Frank Warmerdam](http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2007-March/012167.html):

> The .csv files are primarily intended for EPSG coordinate systems, so
>   it isn't really appropriate to extend them manually.
>
> But you can add your own custom dictionaries in a manner similar to
>   gdal/data/cubewerx_extra.wkt.  These dictionary files consist of lines
>   with a short name, a comma and then the WKT definition of the
>   coordinate system.
>
> You can reference such a definition from SetFromUserInput() and
>   programs that use that function (such as s_srs, a_srs, t_srs for
>   gdal_translate, ogr2ogr and gdalwarp) using the form:
>
> gdal_translate  -a_srs DICT:cubewerx_extra.wkt,41001

I hope this helps. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I did something similar to what you suggested.  My `$GDAL_DATA$` directory is at `/usr/local/share/gdal`, and EPSG 3857 is defined in `pcs.csv` in that folder.  I copied that line to `pcs.override.csv`, and changed the ID (first column) from 3857 to 102100.  At that point, conversions worked without the `-s_srs` flag.

The longer-term solution was to get my source data in a known projection, so that I could use ogr2ogr for format conversion alone, rather than mix in projections.